# Detecting intersection of two WGS84 lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to detect intersection of two WSG84 lines in Matlab given the information below known.

RedLine: `latStart0, lonStart0, latEnd0, lonEnd0`

BlueLine: `latStart1, lonStart1, latEnd1, lonEnd1`
[image: example figure]

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the solution:

```
function intersectionPoint = findIntersection(line1_start, line1_end, line2_start, line2_end)
    line1_start_rad = deg2rad(line1_start);
    line1_end_rad = deg2rad(line1_end);
    line2_start_rad = deg2rad(line2_start);
    line2_end_rad = deg2rad(line2_end);
    
    % Calculate the denominator for the lines
    denom = (line1_end_rad(1) - line1_start_rad(1)) * (line2_end_rad(2) - line2_start_rad(2)) - ...
        (line1_end_rad(2) - line1_start_rad(2)) * (line2_end_rad(1) - line2_start_rad(1));

    if abs(denom) < eps
        intersectionPoint = struct('latitude', NaN, 'longitude', NaN);
        return;
    end

    numer = (line2_end_rad(1) - line2_start_rad(1)) * (line1_start_rad(2) - line2_start_rad(2)) - ...
        (line2_end_rad(2) - line2_start_rad(2)) * (line1_start_rad(1) - line2_start_rad(1));

    t1 = numer / denom;
    
    if t1 < 0
        intersectionPoint = struct('latitude', NaN, 'longitude', NaN);
        return;
    end
    
    % Calculate the intersection point
    lonIntersection_rad = line1_start_rad(2) + (line1_end_rad(2) - line1_start_rad(2)) * t1;
    latIntersection_rad = line1_start_rad(1) + (line1_end_rad(1) - line1_start_rad(1)) * t1;

    latIntersection_deg = rad2deg(latIntersection_rad);
    lonIntersection_deg = rad2deg(lonIntersection_rad);

    intersectionPoint = struct('latitude', latIntersection_deg, 'longitude', lonIntersection_deg);
end
```